# DomXPath query to select links which don't contain "mailto"

Tags: php, domxpath

I tried to get all the links except ones contains 'mailto'. I have tried millions of different things but nothing seems to work. My best attempt was `//a[@href(not(contaıns('maılto')))]` but it didn't work too. I also tried to get all links with //a and then with `$domelement->getAttribute('href')` but it returns the href='mailto:x@x.com' as x@x.com, not with 'mailto'. It automatically cuts the 'mailto' part I don't know why. Anyone has experience about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track using `not()` and `contains()` however your syntax is incorrect (also, I'd use `starts-with()` instead).

```
//a[not(starts-with(@href, 'mailto'))]
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with